# Why does Plot3D omit parts of the surface at kinks?

Tags: plotting

When doing

```
Plot3D[Max[p^2-q^2,0],{p,0,1},{q,-1,1},PlotStyle->White]
```

the result looks like this (with Mathematica 8.0.0.0):

[image]

As you can easily see, at the "kink" where the function starts going above 0, Mathematica leaves a gap in the surface.

Why does it do that, and more importantly, what can I do about it?

Comment: Increasing the number of `PlotPoints` seems to reduce the gap.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: True, but it also increases the memory needed, and doesn't really close the gap. And I've got other cases (with more complicated functions) where the gap gets much larger than in this example. Increasing the number of points isn't really practical in those cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason for this is automatic exclusion detection:

Here the discontinuity in the derivative is ugly:

```
Plot3D[Max[p^2 - q^2, 0], {p, 0, 1}, {q, -1, 1}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can get Mathematica to auto-detect it, and compute the contours precisely, making the plot smooth around the discontinuity:

```
Plot3D[Max[p^2 - q^2, 0], {p, 0, 1}, {q, -1, 1}, 
 Exclusions -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The side effect is a gap, as you noticed.  Often one would prefer this gap to be filled with the same style as the plot.  It can be accomplished by setting [`ExclusionsStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html), like this:

```
Plot3D[Max[p^2 - q^2, 0], {p, 0, 1}, {q, -1, 1}, 
 Exclusions -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT:**  As @celtschk notes, mesh lines or contour lines are not drawn inside the excluded region.  This is very visible for large exclusions and can be prevented by forbidding exclusions with `Exclusions -> None`.  Then the plot can be made smoother by increasing `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints`.  Here's an example:

```
Plot3D[UnitStep[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, that gives exactly what I want.

Comment: Correction: *Almost* exactly: The grid lines are not drawn in the filled gap, which gets very visible for large gaps.

Comment: @celtschk You mean the mesh, right?  (`Mesh`).  That's true, the workaround would be `Exclusions -> None` and increasing `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPloints` manually until you get the right result. (I.e. the same thing you did.)

Comment: Yeah, I meant the mesh. `Exclusions->None` plus sufficiently high `MaxRecursion` indeed did the trick. Thank you again.

Comment: @celtschk The refinement in Mma's [adaptive](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Adaptive3DPlotting/) [plotting](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AdaptivePlotting/) is based on the curvature, so it'll converge fast around a discontinuity of the derivative (where the curvature is infinite).  `MaxRecursion` just controls the number of allowed recursive refinement steps.