# Plot showing discontinuity where it shouldn't

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to integrate a continuous function with a kink and I did it two ways and both ways the plot of the result shows a discontinuity. I also later want to differentiate the Integrated function.

```
a=5;
DSolve[Y'[H] == Max[H, a], Y[H], H]
{{Y[H] -> C[1] + 1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H])}}
```

or alternatively

```
Integrate[Max[H, a], H]
```

I get

$
\begin{array}{ll}
 \Big\{ & 
  \begin{array}{ll}
   5 H & H\leq 5 \\
   \frac{25}{2}+\frac{H^2}{2} & \text{True}
\end{array}
\end{array}
$

When I plot the output from the ODE or Plot what I get from the result of the Integration command, I get the same plot, of course, but with this discontinuity at $a$.

```
Plot[1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H]), {H, 4.9, 5.1}]
```

I get:

[image: Plot with discontinuity]

Why is this happening? If I do other operations with this function, is Mathematica gonna treat it as a continuous function or a discontinuous one? I can't remember my math right now but this new function should be differentiable also right since it was the result of an Integration?

When I do this:

```
 FullSimplify[D[1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H]), H]]
```

I get:

$
\begin{array}{ll}
 \{ & \begin{array}{ll}
         5 & H<5 \\
         H & H>5 \\
         \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
   \end{array}
\end{array}
$

Is the fact that I am getting this `Indeterminate` in the middle something to do with the discontinuity?

Comment: Try e.g. `Plot[1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H]), {H, 4.9, 5.1}, PlotPoints -> 300]`

Comment: @Artes ok that worked. Thanks! Do you have a sense of why I am getting an Intermediate when I differentiate?

Comment: Try a simpler case, e.g. : `D[ UnitStep[x], x]`, `UnitStep` is a discontinuous function at `0`.

Comment: @Artes but `1/2 (2 a x + (a - x)^2 UnitStep[-a + x])` is a continuous and even differentiable function whose derivative should be `Max[x,a]`. I guess MMA is not able to figure this out and I need to communicate it to MMA somehow.

Comment: The gap in the plot can also be removed using the option setting `Exclusions->None`. If you plot `PiecewiseExpand[1/2 (2 a h + (a - h)^2 UnitStep[-a + h])]` you also get the same gap at `h=5` although `D[PiecewiseExpand[1/2 (2 a h + (a - h)^2 UnitStep[-a + h])],h]` does not have the `Indeterminate` piece; but `Plot` "sees" some discontinuity in both functions, and inreasing the setting for `PlotPoints` reduces the size of gap, and `Exclusions->None` removes it. (Mma V 8.04.0, Windows Vista 64bit)

Comment: Related: [(4797)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4797/121)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to use `Exclusions->None` as option to `Plot`.

The gap happens exactly where `UnitStep[-a+h]` has its discontinuity

```
With[{a = 5}, 
  Plot[{1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H]), 
    UnitStep[-a + H] + 25}, {H, 4.9, 5.1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This behavior was introduced, when Wolfram decided, that discontinuities should be discontinuous displayed in `Plot`. When you look at the function, to see whether or not there is a crack, you should use `Limit`. Here you see, that the derivative is the same from both directions

```
With[{a = 5},
   Limit[D[1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H]), H], H -> 5, 
    Direction -> #]
   ] & /@ {1, -1}  

(* {5, 5} *)
```

Therefore, it seems `Plot` internals work as if there is a discontinuity where there is none. The first two examples in the following suggest that forcing `Plot` to sample more points does not remove the "discontinuity". The third one (`Exclusions->None`) explicitly forces `Plot` to treat the line as continuous, and the last one (I think ... somehow) makes `Plot` internals "realize" that there are, in fact, no discontinuities in the first argument.

```
 Grid[{{Plot[1/2 (2 a h + (a - h)^2 UnitStep[-a + h]), {h, 4., 6},
        PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 300, 
        ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Red],
        PlotLabel -> HoldForm[PlotPoints -> 50]],
   Plot[1/2 (2 a h + (a - h)^2 UnitStep[-a + h]), {h, 4., 6},
        PlotPoints -> 800, ImageSize -> 300, 
        ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Red],
        PlotLabel -> HoldForm[PlotPoints -> 800]]},
  {Plot[1/2 (2 a h + (a - h)^2 UnitStep[-a + h]), {h, 4., 6},
       PlotPoints -> 10, ImageSize -> 300, Exclusions -> None,
       PlotLabel -> HoldForm[{Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 10}]],
   Plot[1/2 (2 a hh + (a - hh)^2 UnitStep[-a + hh]) /. hh -> h, {h, 4., 6},
       PlotPoints -> 10, ImageSize -> 300, 
       ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Red],
       PlotLabel -> HoldForm[{Plot[f[x] /. x -> h, _], PlotPoints -> 10}]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, it's not a comment ;-) Please review my additions.

Comment: @halirutan, very nice, thank you.

Comment: @kguler Thank for for such an excellent explanation! I learnt about using limits in mathematica, especially inside a plot, as an additional bonus. :) It's interesting that you spotted that taking limits makes mathematica realize that the curve is continuous. cool beans!

Comment: @Amatya, thanks for the accept.

Comment: I know this is quite old... but thanks! I think the last option about using ReplaceAll and replace the variable for another is much better than the ubiquitous solution of Exclusions -> None, just to have the flexibility of still be able to plot discontinuous functions properly.

Comment: mmm… after having played a little more, the 3rd and 4th solutions are perhaps equivalent. Discontinuities (such as asymptotes) are no longer excluded using `ReplaceAll` (or, in this case, detected)  and are actually plotted, as when using `Exclusions->None`. These gaps are a nuisance indeed… I need it to be able to both deal with discontinuities and don’t leave gaps.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions (V11 or at least by V11.3), the gap shown at a point discontinuity is almost negligible, but present:

```
Plot[0.1 UnitStep[1/200 - a + H] + 
   1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H]), {H, 4.9, 5.1}];
GraphicsRow[{%, Show[%, PlotRange -> {{4.995, 5.002}, Automatic}]}, ImageSize->Large]
```

[image]

Here's a general utility that removes exclusions that are continuities, but includes actual discontinuities (`Exclusions -> None` connects all segments, even the truly discontinuous ones):

```
ClearAll[includeContinuousSingularities];
SetAttributes[includeContinuousSingularities, HoldAll];
includeContinuousSingularities[tol_ /; NumericQ[tol]] := 
  Function[p, includeContinuousSingularities[p, tol], HoldAll];
includeContinuousSingularities[Plot[f_, {v_, a_, b_}, rest___], tol_: 1.*^-10] :=
 Module[{sing, disc},
  sing = Flatten@ Apply[And, DeleteCases[
    Simplify`FunctionSingularities[f, {v}, {"ALL", "IGNORE", "PWMINMAX"}], {}], {2}];
  sing = DeleteDuplicates@ Flatten@ Quiet@
       DeleteCases[NSolve[# && a < v < b, v] & /@ sing, _NSolve | {} | {{}}];
  disc = Equal @@@ Pick[sing,
     Chop[Block[{v = v /. #}, f] - Limit[f, #], tol] =!= 0 & /@ sing];
  Plot[f, {v, a, b}, rest, Exclusions -> disc]
  ]

Plot[
 0.1 UnitStep[1/200 - a + H] + 1/2 (2 a H + (a - H)^2 UnitStep[-a + H]),
 {H, 4.9, 5.1}] // includeContinuousSingularities;
GraphicsRow[{%, Show[%, PlotRange -> {{4.995, 5.002}, Automatic}]}, ImageSize->Large]
```

[image]

One could use `Solve` instead of `NSolve`, but `NSolve` over a bounded interval is pretty robust.  One might also put a time constraint (`TimeConstrained`) on `NSolve`.  With numerical methods, one has to be careful of comparing results; hence, I used `Chop`.  The tolerance parameter `tol` is probably unnecessary, unless the function values are really small.  See also [Plot a piecewise function with black and white disks marking discontinuities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities/39466#39466).