# Gaps in curves from ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

Why do I get gaps in my plots below? Looking at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13672/12558) post suggests that using `Exclusions-> None` should fix the problem if there is a discontinuity. However there is no discontinuity in my case. So why do I get the gaps? Using `Exclusions-> None` does fix the problem so it must be a similar but different problem.

```
Module[{H, Ha, A = 0.015, α = 4, β, γ = 0.001},
 H[β_] := (
  E^(-2 π α (I β + γ)) (-I E^(
      2 π α (I β + γ)) (β - 
        I γ) + (I β + γ) Cos[2 π α] - 
     Sin[2 π α]))/(-1 + β^2 - 
   2 I β γ - γ^2);
 Ha[β_] := 
  A (I β + γ)/(1 - (β - I γ)^2);

 pp = ParametricPlot[{ReIm@Ha[β], ReIm@H[β]}, {β, 0,
     2},
   ImageSize -> 11 72, PlotRange -> All
   ]

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
Note that there is a gap in the yellow curve near the horizontal axis as well as the obvious one in the blue curve.

To look more closely I did

```
Length@Cases[pp, _Line, ∞]
(* 4 *)
```

This shows that the blue and yellow curves have been each been split up into two sections. I thought it might be due to the course sampling but increasing the `PlotPoints` to 200 still leaves a gap in the blue curve.

Now with `Exclusions-> None`  added I get a good result and there are now just two lines as expected.

```
Module[{H, Ha, A = 0.015, α = 4, β, γ = 0.001},
 H[β_] := (
  E^(-2 π α (I β + γ)) (-I E^(
      2 π α (I β + γ)) (β - 
        I γ) + (I β + γ) Cos[2 π α] - 
     Sin[2 π α]))/(-1 + β^2 - 
   2 I β γ - γ^2);
 Ha[β_] := 
  A (I β + γ)/(1 - (β - I γ)^2);

 pp = ParametricPlot[{ReIm@Ha[β], ReIm@H[β]}, {β, 0,
     2},
   ImageSize -> 11 72, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None
   ]

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So why do I get the gaps?

Comment: Side note: adding `PlotPoints -> 500` makes the plot much smoother.

Comment: Try `MaxRecursion -> 10, PlotPoints -> 60`, along `Exclusions -> None`.  The function has some strange behaviour at that point which happens not to show up in this particular plot.  Mathematica detects and excludes it anyway.  Your first function has very rapid change there, thus with uniform sampling in $\beta$ it look ugly and it needs an unusually high number of recursive refinements to smooth it out.

Comment: @Szabolcs You values are not quite enough in Version 11.0.0.`PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 10` does not do it but then increasing  the MaxRecursion to 15 does. What is odd is that in the original plot the yellow curve has a gap despite it being smooth. Is there also an issue with plotting vertically? Thanks for your input.

Comment: It looks completely smooth with 11.0.1.  Perhaps you should upgrade, point releases bring many bugfixes ...

Comment: you may want to separately plot the two functions as `Show[{ParametricPlot[H],ParametricPlot[Ha]}]` so that you can independently set the parameters,

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase the number of `PlotPoints` to get a smooth curve and use the option `Exclusions` to force evaluations close to the exclusion points (i.e., close the gaps).

```
Module[
 {H, Ha, A = 0.015, α = 4, β, γ = 0.001},
 H[β_] :=
  (E^(-2 π α (I β + γ)) (-I E^(2 π α (I β + γ)) (β - I γ) +
       (I β + γ) Cos[2 π α] - Sin[2 π α]))/
   (-1 + β^2 - 2 I β γ - γ^2);
 Ha[β_] := A (I β + γ)/(1 - (β - I γ)^2);
 pp = ParametricPlot[
   {ReIm@Ha[β], ReIm@H[β]}, {β, 0, 2},
   Exclusions -> {β == 2},
   ImageSize -> Medium,
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotPoints -> 300]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  The gaps are closed when the `Exclusion` is at the max value of `β`

```
Manipulate[
 Module[
  {H, Ha, A = 0.015, α = 4, β, γ = 0.001},
  H[β_] :=
   (E^(-2 π α (I β + γ)) (-I E^(2 π α (I β + γ)) (β - I γ) +
        (I β + γ) Cos[2 π α] - Sin[2 π α]))/
    (-1 + β^2 - 2 I β γ - γ^2);
  Ha[β_] := A (I β + γ)/(1 - (β - I γ)^2);
  pp = ParametricPlot[
    {ReIm@Ha[β], ReIm@H[β]}, {β, 0, βmax},
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotPoints -> 300,
    Exclusions -> {β == βmax}]],
 {{βmax, 2}, 1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: This is very odd. The problem is close to \[Beta]==1  but adding  an exclusion at  \[Beta]==2 does help. It does not help to add the exclusion at \[Beta]==1. What is going on? Thanks for investigating.

Comment: @Hugh - see edit.

Comment: Experimenting it appears that any value of Exclusion works. It even works to put `Exclusions -> {}` Not a clear behaviour. Very difficult to understand what is happening.

Comment: the functions (both `H` and `Ha` are actually smooth and continuous. (both real and imaginary parts). they just vary very rapidly near `beta=1`, so that it appears to jump if the sampling is too coarse.  Setting a large `PlotPoints` (1000 works) is all you need here.