# Why does using `Plot3D` with `RealAbs` cause a white space at kink but using `Abs` doesn't?

Tags: plotting, graphics, rendering

Consider the following plot:

```
Plot3D[RealAbs[(x-5)+y],{x,4.999,5.001},{y,0,0.001}]
```

The above plot has a white space where the derivative has a discontinuous jump (at $y=5$)

If instead I consider

```
Plot3D[Abs[(x-5)+y],{x,4.999,5.001},{y,0,0.001}]
```

The white space is gone.

I understand that, according [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4798/39270), I can get rid of the whitespace by using the `Exclusions` option.

> However, I am wondering why one command produces the whitespace by default and the other doesn't?

(my naive guess would be that because `Abs` thinks the argument is complex, that mathematica doesn't detect an exclusion at the kink)

Comment: Neither of your plot commands are valid. Assuming that you included a range for `y`, the difference presumably has to do with the automatic detection for `Exclusions`. `D[RealAbs[(x - 5) + y], y]` evaluates; whereas, `D[Abs[(x - 5) + y], y]` is meaningless. Including the option `Exclusions -> None` will eliminate the white line.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question and didn't realize I deleted the y range. Ill add them back in.